# How do I get DatePickerDialog to continue to show with an orientation change?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext

I have a DatePickerDialog that launches successfully in a fragment.  When an orientation change occurs the app crashes.  The logcat output says the NPE happens with onDismiss for the DatePickerFragment.  What am I missing here?

Here is partial DatePcikerFragement file:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public DatePickerFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            this, year, month, day);
    return picker;
    }


    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(CardViewActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you call the DatePickerFragment class ??? in oncreate or onresume ???

Comment: in onCreate, see edit above.

Comment: Try to implement onConfigchange Method and do your code accordingly